# UITextField textFieldShouldChange does not give full string

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

My code is

```
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 NSLog(@"%@",petTypeTextFeild.text);

return YES;
}
```

when i type 'a' nothing is printed
when i typenext letter 's'  'a' is printed
I want full text.

Is there any other methode like textFinishChange?
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is the best way to check the proposed new text if you want to still have the option to refuse the edit.

Answer (score 1):

In that method you can't get full text..
If you return Yes then only that particular letter will be allowed and if return No it will not allow to change the text.
And use this method to get complete text.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: This only gives you the text at the end of editing, it can't be used whilst the user is typing.

Comment: Yes..it will give only at the end of editing...Anil solution will meet your requirement

Answer (score 1):

This is a delegate which is called before textField actually changes its value,

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Thats Why you are getting old value, So you should use this line to get the exact value

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *str = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
return YES;
}
```